# How to do a conditional update/delete in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need something that will look for a some records then decide whether to delete or update depending on what the result of the first query is. So for example:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items WHERE itemId = 101) = 0 THEN
  DELETE FROM itemPrice WHERE itemId = 101;
ELSE
  UPDATE itemPrice SET price = 0 WHERE itemId = 101;
END
```

I'm not sure how to do the above, is it possible in just MySQL?

Comment: @lbrahim I've updated it to be a question now, although I feel like I was quite clearly asking for help with the syntax of my statement.

Comment: It sounds as though you are trying to manually constrain the values of `itemId` in your `itemPrice` table based on a relationship with the `itemId` column in the `Items` table.  This is something that MySQL can handle for you via [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).  Perhaps that is all that you're after?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 different sql command:
`DELETE FROM itemPrice WHERE itemId not in (select itemid FROM Items));
UPDATE itemPrice SET price = 0 WHERE itemId in (select itemid FROM Items));`